# progressSweetAlert in R Shiny to Monitor Iterations

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to monitor the iterations in a function and build a progress sweet alert in Shiny. The help example is fine and well understood

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Progress bar in Sweet Alert"),
  useSweetAlert(), # /!\ needed with 'progressSweetAlert'
  actionButton(
    inputId = "go",
    label = "Launch long calculation !"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progressSweetAlert(
      session = session, id = "myprogress",
      title = "Work in progress",
      display_pct = TRUE, value = 0
    )
    for (i in seq_len(50)) {
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "myprogress", value = i*2)
    }
    closeSweetAlert(session = session)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, my use case is slightly different. In the example above, the iterations can be easily monitored because the `updateProgressBar` is capturing the value for `i` inside the `for` loop.

Suppose however, that I have some function that does work iteratively and I put a `printf` in my function to spit out some progress as it is running. Is it possible to capture the value of `i` printed to screen as `myLooper` runs and pass that value to the `updateProgressBar` so it can build the progress bar?

```
myLooper <- function(x){
    for(i in 1:10){
        y <- x + 1
        Sys.sleep(.1)
        printf("%d\n", i)
    }
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progressSweetAlert(
      session = session, id = "myprogress",
      title = "Work in progress",
      display_pct = TRUE, value = 0
    )
        myLooper(2)
      updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "myprogress", value = i*2)
    closeSweetAlert(session = session)
  })

}
```

Comment: do you mean `sprintf`? This function is just a string formatting function. It does not output anything to console. If your function can use `message` to indicate the progress in console, `tryCatch` will be helpful to update the progress.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting `updateProgressBar` in `Looper()`?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Progress bar in Sweet Alert"),
  useSweetAlert(), # /!\ needed with 'progressSweetAlert'
  actionButton(
    inputId = "go",
    label = "Launch long calculation !"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myLooper <- function(x) {
    for(i in 1:10){
      y <- x + 1
      Sys.sleep(.5)
      updateProgressBar(
        session = session, id = "myprogress", value = 10 * i
      )
    }
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progressSweetAlert(
      session = session, id = "myprogress",
      title = "Work in progress",
      display_pct = TRUE, value = 0
    )
    myLooper(2)
    closeSweetAlert(session = session)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Stephane, Voila! That's it. Thank you.